# Error with mongoDB missing } after propert list

Tags: javascript, json, mongodb, bson

With the following code I am getting this error:

```
SyntaxError: missing } after property list <shell>:2:11
```

Does anyone know what I did wrong?

```
db.movie_Collection.insert(
{
    '_id':self generate,
    'movieId':'1',
    'name':'Mission Impossible 14-The AARP Threat',
    'pineappleMetric':'88',
    'releaseYear':'2018',
    'rating':'PG-13',
    'runtime':136,
    'director':'Robert Silva',
    'writer':['Mary Silva','Mario Silva'],
    'productionCompany': {
        'prodCompanyName':'Rinse Wash Repeat',
        'prodCompanyLocation':'USA'
    },
    'budget':127000000,
    'boxOffice':[32000000,15000000]
});
```

Comment: `'_id':self generate,` this is a syntax error, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: '_id': "self generate"